# Suggestions Chips not showing consistently

Tags: javascript, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I was following a [Codelabs tutorial to build Actions for Google Assistant](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/index.html#4) but, *some* suggestion chips are not showing up.

I implement suggestion chips for multiple intents. In order of the conversation flow, it 1st fails to show color options for [Level 2 Step 5](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/index.html#4), then successfully shows yes/no chips for [Level 2 Step 8](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/index.html#7), but fails again to trying to show yes/no chips for [Level 3 Step 9](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-3/index.html#8).

Screenshots from "Display" tab of failed - [color options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zFF1.png), successful - [yes/no](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVp6H.png) and failed - [yes/no](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjhhe.png) (snippet of the JSON text from the "Response" tab are also included in the same order).

Snippets from my fulfillment code are shown in the same sequence:

```js
// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'actions_intent_PERMISSION'. If user
// agreed to PERMISSION prompt, then boolean value 'permissionGranted' is true.

app.intent('actions_intent_PERMISSION', (conv, params, permissionGranted) => {
  if (!permissionGranted) {
    // If the user denied our request, go ahead with the conversation.
    conv.ask(`OK, no worries. What's your favorite color?`);
    conv.ask(new Suggestions('Blue', 'Red', 'Green'));
  } else {
    // If the user accepted our request, store their name in
    // the 'conv.user.storage' object for the duration of the conversation.
    conv.user.storage.userName = conv.user.name.display;
    conv.ask(`Thanks, ${conv.user.storage.userName}. What's your favorite color?`);
    conv.ask(new Suggestions('Blue', 'Red', 'Green'));
  }
});

// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'favorite color'.
// The intent collects a parameter named 'color'.
app.intent('favorite color', (conv, {
  color
}) => {
  const luckyNumber = color.length;
  const audioSound = 'https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/cartoon/clang_and_wobble.ogg';
  if (conv.user.storage.userName) {
    // If we collected user name previously, address them by name and use SSML
    // to embed an audio snippet in the response.
    conv.ask(`<speak>${conv.user.storage.userName}, your lucky number is ` +
      `${luckyNumber}.<audio src="${audioSound}"></audio> ` +
      `Would you like to hear some fake colors?</speak>`);
    conv.ask(new Suggestions('Yes', 'No'));
  } else {
    conv.ask(`<speak>Your lucky number is ${luckyNumber}.` +
      `<audio src="${audioSound}"></audio> ` +
      `Would you like to hear some fake colors?</speak>`);
    conv.ask(new Suggestions('Yes', 'No'));
  }
});

// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'favorite fake color'.
// The intent collects a parameter named 'fakeColor'.
app.intent('favorite fake color', (conv, {
  fakeColor
}) => {
  fakeColor = conv.arguments.get('OPTION') || fakeColor;
  // Present user with the corresponding basic card and end the conversation.
  if (!conv.screen) {
    conv.ask(colorMap[fakeColor].text);
  } else {
    conv.ask(`Here you go.`, new BasicCard(colorMap[fakeColor]));
  }
  conv.ask('Do you want to hear about another fake color?');
  conv.ask(new Suggestions('Yes', 'No'));
});
```

```js
//failed - color options
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "OK, no worries. What's your favorite color?"
            }
          }
        ],
        "suggestions": [
          {
            "title": "Blue"
          },
          {
            "title": "Red"
          },
          {
            "title": "Green"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

// successful yes/no
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "<speak>Your lucky number is 4.<audio src=\"https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/cartoon/clang_and_wobble.ogg\"></audio> Would you like to hear some fake colors?</speak>"
            }
          }
        ],
        "suggestions": [
          {
            "title": "Yes"
          },
          {
            "title": "No"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

//failed - yes/no
{
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "expectUserResponse": true,
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "Here you go."
            }
          },
          {
            "basicCard": {
              "title": "Pink Unicorn",
              "formattedText": "Pink Unicorn is an imaginative reddish hue.",
              "image": {
                "url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_12/assets/0BxFyKV4eeNjDbFVfTXpoaEE5Vzg/style-color-uiapplication-palette2.png",
                "accessibilityText": "Pink Unicorn Color"
              },
              "imageDisplayOptions": "WHITE"
            }
          },
          {
            "simpleResponse": {
              "textToSpeech": "Do you want to hear about another fake color?"
            }
          }
        ],
        "suggestions": [
          {
            "title": "Yes"
          },
          {
            "title": "No"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I originally submitted this as a bug in the github repository https://github.com/actions-on-google/codelabs-nodejs/issues/41

Comment: This does seem odd. Can you add two additional bits of information to your question: (1) Wider screen shots that include the "Display" tab in the simulator, while the Phone setting is set, that show what is being shown on the phone simulator at that time? (2) The (JSON text) contents of the "Response" tab (both when it works and when it doesn't)?

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner I've added new screenshots of the Display tab in the phone setting and the JSON text from response.

Comment: This is a problem of the Simulator, I encounter this regularly. Can you please confirm that Suggestions are working on a real device?

Comment: @Denis I just tried it on my phone and the suggestions chips showed up as expected! Thank you!

Comment: @CuriousCat Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of the Actions on Google Simulator, Suggestions will work on a real device.